# Hypergeometric distribution for large sample sizes

Tags: probability

Let $N$ be the population size, $n$ the number of samples, and $m$ the number of successes for a hypergeometric distribution. In the limit $n \to \infty$, $n / N \to 0$, this converges in distribution to a Gaussian. Are there any known results about the $n / N \to \alpha > 0$ case?